# How can I remove the padding and enlarge images in mobile view

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design

On [my blog](http://jeffreydowellphotography.com/blog/), Im trying to reduce my padding inside the blue box and enlarge my images and remove hover for my mobile views. So far my code will not change it. Im just trying to make it more responsive for touch devices

```
@media only screen and (max-width:800px) {
    #header, #pageWrapper, #footer {
        padding: 30px 20px;
        margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    }  
    h1.logo {
        text-align: center;
        padding-bottom: 10px
    }
    .slide img {
        opacity: 1
    }
    .sqs-active-slide img {
        opacity:1
    }
    .collection-type-gallery #slideshowWrapper .slide img {
        background-color: white !important;
        margin: 2px 0;
    }
    img {
        max-width: 200px;
    }
    .hentry {
        background: #F8F9FC;
        padding: 10px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #E2E7F5;
        border-width: 2px
    }
    .collection-51ca14b1e4b014f2c6e0c3e7 .slide img {
        opacity:1.0;
    }
}
```

Comment: how did you just edit my question?

Comment: the blue line goes outside the background/box, how can i make it stop with the edge of the boxes

Comment: how can i change it then to have the background blue, no border, with just white space in between each posting? instead of having these boxes.

Comment: `.collection-51ca14b1e4b014f2c6e0c3e7 .slide img` ;-)

Comment: what does this refer to @jeromeM

Comment: Nothing, it just look like a security code... I'm actually looking at your code for help.

Comment: What is the size wanted for the image in mobile view?

Comment: I would like to make them 328 wide, which would make them the width of the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the images, you need to use the `!important` declaration to override normal specificity style in the HTML. 
For example if you want to set the new width at 400px:

```
.sqs-gallery-block-grid .slide .margin-wrapper a.image-slide-anchor img {
    width: 400px !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: i added this in, with the 328, and now its off centered and is overlapping the next post.

Comment: also, it isnt applying to posts with more than one image.

Comment: You have to set a `float: left;` on the `.margin-wrapper` div (overlapping).

Comment: added. but it is still pushing the image to the right, and there is too much space below the image.

Comment: Set `left` on image to `0px` and adjust the `width` of the image. I can't fix all, just give you some guideline. Hope it help, do not hesitate to say "thanks" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you right off the bat, your max-width is probably too high. If you are targeting a smartphone it should be at most 640px.